# Why does my 2-layer neural network achieve just 50% accuracy for binary classification?

Tags: python, neural-network

Following a [review post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/266189/), I constructed this dataset for binary classification that contains Fashion MNIST T-shirt vs. Shirt.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()

# generate the indices
idx_digit_train = np.argwhere((y_train == 0) | (y_train == 6)).flatten()
idx_digit_test = np.argwhere((y_test == 0) | (y_test == 6)).flatten()

# construct the training set
y_train_mnist = y_train[idx_digit_train].reshape(-1,1)
x_train_mnist = x_train[idx_digit_train].reshape(-1,28*28)

# construct the test set
y_test_mnist = y_test[idx_digit_test].reshape(-1,1)
x_test_mnist = x_test[idx_digit_test].reshape(-1,28*28)

x_train_mnist = x_train_mnist/255.
x_test_mnist = x_test_mnist/255.

y_train_mnist[y_train_mnist==6]=1
y_test_mnist[y_test_mnist==6]=1

y_train_mnist = np.array(y_train_mnist, dtype=np.float32)
y_test_mnist = np.array(y_test_mnist, dtype=np.float32)
```

Adapted from another [review post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/265908/), I built a 2 layer neural network from scratch with NumPy.

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

class MLPClassifier:
    def __init__(self, eta=.05, n_epoch=10, n_0=2, n_1=2, n_2=1,
          model_w1=[], model_b1=[], model_w2=[], model_b2=[]):
        self.eta = eta
        self.n_epoch = n_epoch
        self.model_w1 = model_w1
        self.model_b1 = model_b1
        self.model_w2 = model_w2
        self.model_b2 = model_b2
        self.n_1 = n_1
        self.n_2 = n_2
        
    def initialize_params(self, n_0, n_1, n_2):
        if len(self.model_w1) == 0:
            self.model_w1 = np.random.random(size=(n_0, n_1))
        if len(self.model_w2) == 0:
            self.model_w2 = np.random.random(size=(n_1, n_2))
        if len(self.model_b1) == 0:
            self.model_b1 = np.random.random(size=(1, n_1))
        if len(self.model_b2) == 0:
            self.model_b2 = np.random.random(size=(1, n_2))
        
    def predict(self, x):
        _, a2 = self.forward_propagation(x)
        yhat = a2 >= 0.5
        return 1*yhat

    def forward_propagation(self, x):
        z1 = np.dot(x, self.model_w1) + self.model_b1
        a1 = sigmoid(z1)
        z2 = np.dot(a1, self.model_w2) + self.model_b2
        a2 = sigmoid(z2)
        return a1, a2
    
    def backward_propagation(self, x, y, a1, a2):
        m = len(x)
        n_1 = self.n_1
        n_2 = self.n_2
        a1 = a1.reshape(m, -1)
        dz2 = a2 - y
        dw2 = np.dot(a1.T, dz2)/m
        dw2 = dw2.reshape(n_1, n_2)
        db2 = np.mean(dz2, keepdims = True)
        dz1 = np.dot(dz2, self.model_w2.T) * (a1*(1-a1))
        dw1 = np.dot(x.T, dz1)/m
        db1 = np.mean(dz1, axis=0)
        return dw2, db2, dw1, db1

    def update_params(self, dw2, db2, dw1, db1):
        self.model_w2 -= self.eta * dw2
        self.model_b2 -= self.eta * db2
        self.model_w1 -= self.eta * dw1
        self.model_b1 -= self.eta * db1

    def fit(self, x, y, verbose=False):
        n_0 = x.shape[-1]
        n_1 = self.n_1
        n_2 = self.n_2
        self.initialize_params(n_0, n_1, n_2)        
        for i in range(self.n_epoch):
            a1, a2 = self.forward_propagation(x)
            dw2, db2, dw1, db1 = self.backward_propagation(x, y, a1, a2)
            self.update_params(dw2, db2, dw1, db1)
```

Per the first post, a Logistic Regression model can achieve

> train accuracy: 0.828583

However, when I trained my handcraft model 1, 2, though 9 epochs and then even 9999 epochs, it just achieve 0.5 accuracy on both train and test sets.

```
classifier = MLPClassifier(.1, 9999)
classifier.fit(x_train_mnist, y_train_mnist, verbose=False)
acc = np.count_nonzero(np.squeeze(classifier.predict(x_train_mnist)) == np.squeeze(y_train_mnist))
```

I also tried a range of numbers for hidden units, none of them worked better.

```
acc_list=[]
for i in np.arange(2, 99):
  for j in range(9):
    classifier = MLPClassifier(.1, j, n_1=i)
    classifier.fit(x_train_mnist, y_train_mnist, verbose=False)
    acc = np.count_nonzero(np.squeeze(classifier.predict(x_train_mnist)) == np.squeeze(y_train_mnist))
    acc_list.append(acc)
```

In contrast to that, the tensorflow version

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train_mnist, y_train_mnist, epochs=20, verbose=1)
```

hit **0.85** after 30 Epochs

Epoch 30/50
375/375 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.3326 - accuracy: 0.8525

What am I missing?

How do I improve my 2-layer handcraft model without adding more layers?

**Note**: My scratch version is also using CrossEntropy.

[image]

click [the colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12_NUfDXVEJVZeGbRUBeaT5EH04z1E0y2?usp=sharing) to run it online.

Comment: lack sigmoid*（1-sigmoid）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in Your code.

1. As You probably want to implement Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD), the idea behind it is to perform **online** training, which basically means that You update the model's parameters after each training example (relatively, after each batch of samples in batch-SGD). Your training loop should thus look like this:

   ```
   for i in trange(self.n_epoch):
       for j in range(0, len(x)):
           a1, a2 = self.forward_propagation(x[i])
           dw2, db2, dw1, db1 = self.backward_propagation(x[i], y[i], a1, a2)
           self.update_params(dw2, db2, dw1, db1)
   ```
2. It seems like You are not including the derivative of the sigmoid function at the very output of the network in `backward_propagation`.
   Moreover, by writing `db2 = np.mean(dz2, keepdims = True)` You are reducing the update of the biases to a scalar value (this is probably not what You want).
   Additionally, there are some issues with array shapes in Your code (be careful with np.reshape - it can output something else than You expect, my humble advice is - don't use it unless You really want to RESHAPE an array).
   Eventually, here is how the backward pass should work:

   ```
   def backward_propagation(self, x, y, a1, a2):
       dz2 = (a2 - y) * (a2*(1-a2))
       dw2 = np.dot(a1.T, dz2) / len(a1)
       db2 = dz2/len(dz2)
       dz1 = np.dot(dz2, self.model_w2.T) * (a1 * (1 - a1))
       dw1 = np.dot(np.expand_dims(x, 1), dz1) / len(x)
       db1 = dz1/len(dz1)
       return dw2, db2, dw1, db1
   ```
3. Finally, initializing the weights with only positive values form a uniform distribution is not the best idea. A good starting point would be to use the standard normal:

   ```
   def initialize_params(self, n_0, n_1, n_2):
       if len(self.model_w1) == 0:
           self.model_w1 = np.random.randn(n_0, n_1)
       if len(self.model_w2) == 0:
           self.model_w2 = np.random.randn(n_1, n_2)
       if len(self.model_b1) == 0:
           self.model_b1 = np.random.randn(1, n_1)
       if len(self.model_b2) == 0:
           self.model_b2 = np.random.randn(1, n_2)
   ```

You can further experiment with reducing the standard deviation parameter of the normal distribution (but do not initialize with zeros!). If You want to dig deeper, search for 'Kaming He initialization' and 'Xavier initialization'.

Eventually, You can try to have a look at the code of open-source DeepLearning libraries (i.e. tensorflow or pytorch). One can really learn a lot from that! Here's for example how the linear layer is implemented in torch: [torch.nn.modules.linear](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html#Linear)

Comment: Thank you so much. Have you tried this answer yourself? Does it work better?

Comment: Please don't be sarcastic at stackoverflow. It wastes everybody's time. I'm sorry, I didn't have the time to run it myself, I just corrected mistakes that I saw. After a second glance, it appears to be more of them. I updated the post - now it learns fine (more than 60% acc after 100 epochs). To replicate the 85% score You'd have to experiment with: weight initialization, batching and batch size, loss functions (Your TF example uses CrossEntropy, You use MeanSquaredError).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not being sarcastic. I didn't agree the 2nd part of your answer though I tried and it didn't work better. I updated my OP (the last math derivation) to show my scratch version is using binary CrossEntropy as well. I guess the 1st part of your answer is the key to my problem, so I upvoted for that. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ah, You're right - the derivation is good. Leave a comment when You succeed at replicating the score.